# deleteColumnAt() or getColumnAt() from range in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a 2 x 10 array of numbers in a range.

I wish to just copy the second column to a google sheet.

I am using the following method but it seems overkill, any other short approaches?

```
  //convert [2 x 10] range results into a an input friendly format minus the first column
  var filteredRows = [];
  var results2Rows = results2.getRows(); 
  for(var i=0;i<results2Rows.length;i++){
    filteredRows.push([results2Rows[i][1]]);
  }
//Set sheetCells 
sheet.getRange(1, 1,  10, 1).setValues(filteredRows);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or in this case [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) makes working with sheets easier:

```
 //convert [2 x 10] range results into a an input friendly format minus the   
  var filteredRows = results2.getRows().map(function(row) {
     return row[1];
  }); 
  //Set sheetCells 
  sheet.getRange(1, 1,  10, 1).setValues(filteredRows);
```

Comment: The result needs to be a two dimensional array. That is what the error means. I didn't try the code, it is about the principle, using a map instead of of a for. You can also try to use a foreach and fill a new array in the sameway. Less effective, but easier to work with.

Comment: and, return row[1] actually returns the second element of the array. not the array itself. Try return splice(0,1). That will return the array with the first element removed.